# Insert Failing Node.js mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I'm working on an EC2 server and I need to insert some data into a mySql table from server-side.

I have verified that the information in the request body is accurate via logging their values to the console i.e. console.log(req.body.name). I also know that my table exists.

My connection pool is defined at the top of the page:

```
  var pool = mysql.createPool({
        host: 'localhost',
        user:'student',
        password: 'default',
        database: 'workouts'
    });
```

My insert inside of a POST function is:

```
pool.query("INSERT INTO workouts(`name`, `reps`, `weight`, `date`, `lbs`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", [req.body.name, req.body.reps, req.body.weight, req.body.date, req.body.lbs],
function(err, result){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
});
});
```

My table was created using professor-supplied code:

```
app.get('/reset-table',function(req,res,next){
var context = {};
pool.query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS workouts", function(err){ //replace your connection pool with the your variable containing the connection pool
var createString = "CREATE TABLE workouts("+
"id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,"+
"name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,"+
"reps INT,"+
"weight INT,"+
"date DATE,"+
"lbs BOOLEAN)";
pool.query(createString, function(err){
context.results = "Table reset";
res.render('home',context);
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: So what's the actual error?

Comment: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to you mysql server for the right syntax to use near ,?,?,?,? at line 1. CODE: ER_PARSE_ER

Comment: I've tried changing the query to: ....VALUES(?) and the inserted object to var package = {name: req.body.name, reps: req.body.reps, weight: req.body.weight, date: req.body.weight, date: req.body.date, lbs: req.body.lbs};   Then I get an error ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE